# Show there exists differentiable $g : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f(\vec{x}) = g(||\vec{x}||)$ for $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \left \{0 \right \} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function s.t $\nabla f \neq 0$ and:
>
> $y \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} -  x \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =0 \\
> z \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} -  y \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} =0$
>
> Show there is a differentiable $g : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f(x,y,z) = g(||(x,y,z)||)$

I tried using spherical coordinates to show that the gradient is only determined by $r$ which I think should help, but I had some trouble with the algebra, help appreciated.

Comment: In your notation, $x=(x,y,z)$?

Comment: The idea would be to show $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\varphi}f = 0$.

Comment: @mrsamy no, x is the first coordinate

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Yes I tried showing that but it didn't work for the $\varphi$ partial derivative

Comment: @paxtibimarce: then what do mean writing $f(x)$ and $g(\|x\|)$? Typos?

Comment: @mrsamy Thanks, I thought it was obvious from context, but edited anyway

Comment: Alternatively, use the equations to see that $\nabla f(x,y,z)$ is parallel to the position vector $(x,y,z)$. Do you see why that finishes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $g(r,\theta,\phi) := f(r\sin\theta\cos\phi, r\sin\theta\sin\phi, r\cos\theta)$.
Our assumptions say
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}r\sin\theta\sin\phi = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}r\sin\theta\sin\phi$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}r\cos\theta = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}r\sin\theta\sin\phi$$
We have
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \phi} = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}r\sin\theta\sin\phi + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}r\sin\theta\sin\phi = 0$$
so $g$ in fact does not depend on $\phi$ and we can fix $\phi = \frac\pi2$ so
$$g(r,\theta) = f(0, r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta).$$
We have
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}r\cos\theta - \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}r\sin\theta = 0$$
so $g$ doesn't depend on $\theta$ either. Therefore $g(r,\theta,\phi) = g(r)$ and is differentiable.

Taking $(x,y,z)$ from a dense subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$ we can define $$(r,\theta,\phi) = \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \arctan\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}z, \arctan\frac{y}x\right)$$
and notice
$$f\left(x,y,z\right) = f(r\sin\theta\cos\phi, r\sin\theta\sin\phi, r\cos\theta) = g(r,\theta,\phi) = g(r)= g(\|(x,y,z)\|).$$
By continuity the result extends to all of $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Taking $(x,y,z)$ from a dense subset...".
I don't really get why that is necessary.

Comment: @paxtibimarce Well, the denominators have to be nonzero so we can define $(r,\theta,\phi)$ as stated on the set $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 : x \ne 0, z \ne 0\}$. On $S$ we get the equality of continuous functions $f(x,y,z) = g(\|(x,y,z)\|)$. Since $S$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}^3$, the equality holds on all of $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Since I prefer a more conceptual approach, note that you can deduce from the two equations that
$$\nabla f(x,y,z) = \lambda(x,y,z)(x,y,z)$$
for some function $\lambda$. Since the gradient of a differentiable function is everywhere orthogonal to the level surfaces of that function, this tells you that the function $f$ is constant on spheres centered at the origin. Thus, $f(x,y,z) = g(\|(x,y,z)\|)$ for some function $g$.

(If you prefer, you can see that the directional derivative is $0$ in any direction tangent to such a sphere, because that directional derivative is given by the dot product of the gradient and the tangent vector, and we all know that $(x,y,z)$ is the normal to the sphere centered at the origin passing through the point $(x,y,z)$.)

Comment: Ratio and proportion. The first equation tells you that $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})$ is a scalar multiple of $(x,y)$ (away from $x=0$ and $y=0$) and likewise for the second equation. But then you can take care of these cases.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on how you deduce the function is constant on spheres?

Comment: I can imagine it but I'm just not sure how to show it formally

Comment: Well, I gave the argument in the parenthetic second paragraph. The function stays constant if you move orthogonal to the position vector, which means along the sphere through that point. You know that the normal vector to a sphere centered at the origin is the position vector at every point, and there can be only one surface with that property.

Comment: Any point $\boldsymbol{r}=(x,y,z)\ne(0,0,0)$ is joined to $(0,r,0),$
$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},$ by an arc of a circle, centre $O,$ parameter
$t,$ on which (abusing notation):
$\boldsymbol{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}=r^2,$ whence
$\boldsymbol{r}\cdot(d\boldsymbol{r}/dt)=0;$ and excepting at most
one point, $y\ne0,$ therefore $\nabla f$ is a multiple of
$\boldsymbol{r};$ therefore (chain rule)
$df(\boldsymbol{r})/dt=(\nabla f)\cdot(d\boldsymbol{r}/dt)=0;$
therefore $f(\boldsymbol{r})=f(0,r,0)=g(r),$ say.